# How can I send an code block in discord.js embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to send an embed with a codeblock. In discord a code block is set with three `

What can I do to put `oldMessage.cleanContent` and `newMessage.cleanContent` in a code block?

Here is my code:

```
client.on('messageUpdate', function(oldMessage, newMessage) {

    if (newMessage.channel.type == 'text' && newMessage.cleanContent != oldMessage.cleanContent) {

        var log = newMessage.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name.includes('member-log'))
        if (log != null)

                var sEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor("e8a515")
                .setTitle(`:information_source: A Message Was Edited!`)
                .setDescription(`**USER**\n${newMessage.author.username}`)
                .addField(`Before `,` ${oldMessage.cleanContent} `) //what can i do to put oldMessage.cleanContent in codeblock
                .addField(`After`,`${newMessage.cleanContent} `)
                log.send(sEmbed);
                
                
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways both are correct:

You just comment the comma with quotation

````
.addField(`Before `,"```" + ` ${oldMessage.cleanContent} `+"```")
````

Or you can comment it with slash

```
.addField(`Before `,` \`\`\` ${oldMessage.cleanContent} \`\`\` `)
```